# How to enable Qt completion with clangd in Neovim?

Tags: neovim, lsp, mason, clangd

I use `nvim-cmp`. I have installed the `clangd` with Mason, and configured it with `lsp-config.nvim as:

```lua
local capabilities = require('cmp_nvim_lsp').default_capabilities()

lspconfig.clangd.setup {
    capabilities = capabilities,
    cmd = {vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/mason/bin/clangd"},
    filetypes = { "c", "cpp", "h", "hpp", "objc", "objcpp", "cuda", "proto" }
}
```

When I open Qt program, I get errors that there are no Qt modules found:

[image]

This may be happening because of `Qt` location which is at `~/Qt/`. Its contents are:

```
➜  ~ ls ~/Qt
 5.15.2
 6.6.0
 Docs
 Examples
 InstallationLog.txt
 Licenses
 MaintenanceTool.app
 MaintenanceTool.dat
 MaintenanceTool.ini
'Qt Creator.app'
 QtDesignStudio
 README.txt
 Tools
 build-charts-Desktop_arm_darwin_generic_mach_o_64bit-Debug
 build-login_page-Qt_6_5_2_6_5_2-Debug
 build-msgtest-Qt_6_5_2_6_5_2-Debug
 components.xml
 dist
 installerResources
 licenseInfo.txt
 network.xml
```

I am on arm macOS and installed Qt with Qt maintance tool (brew install is broken). How to make `clangd` work with Qt in nvim? My current Neovim config is [here](https://github.com/Dolfost/dotfiles/tree/main/nvim).

Comment: Do you have a `compile_commands.json` file in the root of your project that describes how each compilation unit should be compiled (in particular setting the `/I` flag for each)?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt No, i have no `compile_commands.json` file.

Comment: Edits explaining how an answer worked are not appropriate for a question. Feel free to suggest edits on answers or to post your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `clangd` LSP server use the `compile_commands.json` to know what are the compile flags used for each compilation units.

`compile_commands.json`:

```
[
  {
    "directory": path/to/project/root,
    "command": "/usr/bin/clang++ -x c++ main.cpp -Ipath/to/QT",
    "file": "main.cpp"
  },
]
```

The `compile_commands.json` can be generated from the compilation command using [Bear](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear).

Comment: I use cmake (which generates makefile) to compile my application. Is there a way to get stuff out of it so it will be automated? Next is not so necessary: I would like to set up the lsp on the vim side so I would not have to add `compile_commands.json` to every project.

Comment: It seems that [Bear](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear) is a tool that generate the `compile_commands.json` from the build command (On Windows I'm using a Visual Studio plugin to do the same).

Comment: If the solution address your problem maybe could you accept the solution using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: Thank You for details!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) I'm glad we could solve your problem ;-)

Comment: I updated the post, and found out amazing thing about bear and cmake! Hope You will find it interesting.